# How to get eclipse code formatter to wrap assignment statements onwards = operator

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter, eclipse-formatter

I'm using eclipse code formatter, and I've set maximum line length to 120.
If an assignment statement is longer than 120 characters, for example

```
private Map<Instruction, LocalRegisterAssignmentInformation> instructionRegisterMap = new IdentityHashMap<Instruction, LocalRegisterAssignmentInformation>();
```

I would like the formatter to wrap this line and make the statement look like this:

```
private Map<Instruction, LocalRegisterAssignmentInformation> instructionRegisterMap
  = new IdentityHashMap<Instruction, LocalRegisterAssignmentInformation>();
```

But the formatter doesn't seem to wrap it. I tried finding relevant options in the eclipse formatter profile settings, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your Java formatter profile as follows:

1. In ***Line Wrapping*** select ***Expressions > Assignments***
2. Set ***Line wrapping policy*** to ***Wrap where necessary***
3. Check the checkbox ***Wrap before operator***